# Controlling MS Word from C++ mfc program when MS Word is already open

Tags: c++, ms-word, mfc, ole

I have a C++ mfc application that needs to convert a .rtf file to a .docx file.  It works correctly unless there is a copy of Word already open when the program runs. The second copy of Word also tries to open the .rtf file but fails because my copy of Word has already locked it.  The problem does not occur in the Debug version, only in the Release version, which makes it very difficult to see what is going wrong.  Any suggestions?  Here is the code:

```
bool CSMXLabDlg::CopyDocToWord(CString strFileToCopy, CString strBackupFile)
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL); // Load COM library DLLs into current thread

    CString strFileToSave = strFileToCopy.Left(strFileToCopy.GetLength() - 4) + TEXT(".docx");
    CString strLockPassword = TEXT("********************");

    USES_CONVERSION;
    _variant_t vFileName(A2W(strFileToCopy));
    _variant_t vSaveName(A2W(strFileToSave));
    _variant_t vLockPassword(A2W(strLockPassword));
    COleVariant vWordDefault((short)16);
    COleVariant vWordCurrent((long)65535, VT_I4);
    COleVariant vDoNotSaveChanges((short)0);
    COleVariant vOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);
    VARIANT vMissing; // VARIANT defining a missing/optional parameter.
    vMissing.vt = VT_ERROR;
    vMissing.scode = DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND;
    long lAllowOnlyRevisions = 0;

    CApplication wordApp; // Variable to hold the Word program

    TRY
    {
        wordApp.CreateDispatch(_T("Word.Application")); // create the instance of Word
        wordApp.put_Visible(FALSE); // make our instance invisible to user 

        CDocuments docs(wordApp.get_Documents()); // Get the Application.Documents collection object
        CDocument0 doc(docs.Open(&vFileName, &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing,
            &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing,
            &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing,
            &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing)); //Open the file
            doc.put_TrackRevisions(true);

        doc.Protect(lAllowOnlyRevisions, &vMissing, &vLockPassword, &vMissing, &vMissing);

        doc.SaveAs2(&vSaveName, &vWordDefault, &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing,
            &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing,
            &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing,
            &vMissing, &vMissing, &vMissing, &vWordCurrent);
        doc.Close(&vOptional, &vOptional, &vOptional);
        doc.ReleaseDispatch(); // free the COM resources held by our Document object.
        docs.ReleaseDispatch(); // free the COM resources held by our Documents collection object.
        wordApp.Quit(&vDoNotSaveChanges, &vMissing, &vMissing); // Close the Application
        wordApp.ReleaseDispatch(); // free the COM resources held by our Application object.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying in Debug mode you can open an .rtf file twice?

Comment: No. I'm saying that the Debug version of the program does not cause the other copy of MS Word to do anything at all, which is exactly what I intended. It is only the Release version that invokes the second copy of Word, which it should not do. There is also another knock-on fault when the Release version of the program is used: the second copy of Word subsequently intercepts a ShellExecute Print instruction intended to cause WordPad to print the .rtf file. The second copy of Word then prints whatever document it had open.